# Laravel 5 - ErrorException failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I've just `git clone` a repository of mine containing a Laravel 5.1 project. I've gone through the normal steps to get it up and running (setup the webserver, db, etc). I've now gone to the web address I configured and i'm getting the following error message:

```
ErrorException in compiled.php line 6648:
file_put_contents(/3c7922efc24ab13620cd0f35b1fdaa61): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Any idea's what folder it's trying to access?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To solve this problem I needed to create a few folder's that were missing from my install. You require the following folders to be readable and writable by your www user:

```
/storage
/storage/cache
/storage/framework
/storage/framework/sessions
/storage/framework/views
/storage/framework/cache
/storage/logs
```

Also, set the folder permissions to `775`. From the root directory run the command: `sudo chmod -R 755 storage`

Comment: Probably it works also if you assign 775 permissions to all folders

Comment: Don't forget to set group owner to www-data. `sudo chown root:www-data -R storage/`

Comment: @ClaudioKing you would regret assigning write permissions to all directories when your web server gets exploited in an attack and it can overwrite all your source files. The other directories should be owned by the user/group in charge of maintenance, with read-only access to other users – including the web server.

Comment: Following this up with `sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage` worked for me

Answer (score 60):

I solved the problem with this solution, clarifying that if you have Windows, you apply lines 1 and 3 and it works the same.

```
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 storage/
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please translate this answer into English, which is the official 

language of this site. Otherwise this, maybe useful, answer might be removed. Thank you very much. See 

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2275490

Comment: Just to state the obvious for anyone viewing this discussion.... if you give any of your folders 777 permissions, you are allowing ANYONE to read, write and execute any file in that directory!!!

Comment: In my case, I had to be at root level using sudo su command and the assign permission 777 to current directory

Comment: This is a bad suggestion. Opening up your stack to all sorts of remote exploits.

Answer (score 8):

If nothing help you and if you work on windows with docker it can be the issue that wrong symlink you have, you can try:

```
ln -s /var/www/storage/app/public /var/www/public/storage
```

And after that:

`chown -R $USER:www-data storage`

`chmod -R 777 storage`

on docker bash.

Comment: if `chown -R $USER:www-data storage` is not working with you guys, try `chown -R www-data:www-data storage`. Lastly, do not use `777`, instead use `755`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ubuntu, most likely you have to give permissions to that folder storage

cd into the project and
use the command -> sudo chmod 755 storage/*

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem in my **localhost** and the problem was that I was trying to upload a file larger than  `upload_max_filesize` in my *php.ini* file .
 just updating this to greater value and restart my server solved the problem ,, if you having similar problem this might be the case

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Linux distribution with SELinux enabled, here is what you need to do:

```bash
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/my-app/storage
sudo chown -R nginx /var/www/html/my-app/storage
sudo chmod -R u+w /var/www/html/my-app/storage
```

This should set the proper context for the storage directory, allowing the web server to write to it.

Comment: this worked in Laravel 10; __preferred because it does not use the dangerous chmod 777__

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem lately with my tests, and resolved it through: composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve a similar issue since I don't have access to the terminal to run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /thedirectory`

in

```
config/filesystem.php

 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Then in my uploader controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

  $file_path= Storage::path('public/importable');
        
  if (!is_dir($file_path)) {mkdir( $file_path,0775, true);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had this issue on Laravel (9 or later) while trying to seed CSV files, and some of the files work but some throw this error, I found out that just running

```
php artisan cache: clear
```

did the trick

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35304079)

Answer (score 0):

in my case in windows

problem is not permission.

and also cache: clear command can't solve.

but the problem is:

if you have folders there in dev or local machine that forget to remove them, your request can't access to replace it. and this error occurred.

solution is to remove all things by

```
php artisan media-library:clear

php artisan media-library:clean
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it was because the single file was owned by root...written at some point when I setup the files, and the app couldn't read it. Solution could be to change ownership, get rid of it, etc.

Answer (score -1):

For me solution was to change folder owner of laravel project. Ensure that is your own user and not root:www-data.

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

Answer (score -2):

Run the following command in the directory that is being triggered to check the permissions:

`ls -lah`

Then if there was any issue you can correct it with:

`sudo chown -R username:group directory`