# Laravel-Docker Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, permissions

It's my first time with docker and i install docker in Linux with this commands

```
$ sudo apt install docker.io
$ sudo snap install docker
```

then create a Laravel app with:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | sudo bash
```

then

```
cd example-app
```

and run the server with

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

and i get this message in the browser

The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/d21bc1965d8c501e5e18921c4eb8ea6ec1e5686e.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}} Context: {"exception":{}}

Thanks for any help <3

Comment: Please copy and paste the error here as text.  No one wants to click and look at an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is caused by you creating the Laravel app using `sudo`. The docs example does not use sudo. You should create it as:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

However, if you wish to keep the current build you need to give adequate permissions to that folder, a quick fix is to run

```
chmod -R 775 storage/
```

if that  doesn't solve it you could run 777 but be aware 777 this not recommended

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
```

You'll probably run into this problem again on other folders. You can run the above code changing "storage" to another folder name.

You can also check the permissions by running `ls -la` in a directory in your terminal.

check out [Laravel 5 - ErrorException failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460874/laravel-5-errorexception-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

and  https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Comment: Thanks, i'll check out about 77 permission means.